# Pickle won't load dictionary from file which contains object references

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I have encountered following problem. I have a class in which I create object of it. Then I call the method from another module which put the name of the object and reference to it in dictionary, pickles it and saves in a file called "shared.pkl" which is in resources package. So my structure look something like this:

```
├── app/
    ├── package1/
    ├──     ├── module1.py
    ├── 
    ├── package2/
    ├──     ├── module2.py
    ├──    
    ├── 
    ├── resources/
            ├── shared.pkl
```

My class in module1.py looks like this:

```
class TestObject:

    def __init__(self):
          pass

def main():

   test_object = TestObject()
   module2.save_to_file(name, test_object)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have imported module2 into module1, no worries. That is not the problem. This is how my method looks like in module2.

```
shared_dict = {}
DATA_PATH = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__package__, 'resources/')
DB_FILE=pkg_resources.resource_filename(__package__,
'resources/shared.pkl')

global shared_dict
def save_to_file(name, remote_object):
   try:
       fp = open(DB_FILE, "rb")
       shared_dict = pickle.load(fp)
       shared_dict.update({name: remote_object})
       fp = open("shared.pkl", "wb")
       print(shared_dict)
       pickle.dump(shared_dict, fp)
   except Exception as e:
       fp = open(DB_FILE, "wb")
       shared_dict.update({name: remote_object})
       print(shared_dict)
       pickle.dump(shared_dict, fp)
   finally:
       fp.close()
```

When I run the program for the first time shared.pkl is not found and exception is caught which creates file and inserts data in it. However when I run the program for the second time it get stuck at `shared_dict = pickle.load(fp)`. In the debugging mode it only says `loader={SourceLoader}<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f5ada68cba8>`

I don't know if it has something to do or not with the class, i.e because the class of the object is in another module and therefore cannot be unpickled.

P.S. I know this isn't the most proper way to handle reading from files and writing in them but forgive me, I am a beginner.

**UPDATE-SOLUTION**
Since pickle does not have possibility to pickle *main* module, using dill instead solved the problem. Dill is an extension of pickle, with much more possibilities.

Comment: note that you're using read mode to write to your file in `save_to_file` at first: `pickle.dump(shared_dict, fp)` that cannot work, and the exception handling probably does the job but it's ugly

Comment: Thanks for that note. I forgot one line, which opens file for writing again. Do you have any suggestion how to handle such combination of reading and writing (i.e creating a file if it doesn't already exist)

Comment: create an empty dict and only load if file exists, that's all